# Auto backup mysql database in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, backup, localhost, database-backup

Can i backup the mysql database automatically every week like scheduled job in local Phpmyadmin.

if possible i would like to take the each database separate file.Is this possible !

Thanks

Comment: Short answer - no, even if were possible it would be a bad idea to use phpmyadmin to run this. If you want a recommendation of how you should do this then we'd need to know what OS it runs on.

Comment: @symcbean:windows xp , windows 7 or Ubuntu any thing is ok

Comment: Hi, have you tried this solution? https://mysqlbackupftp.com/mysql-blog/backup-phpmyadmin-automatically/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use phpmyadmin for critical maintenance tasks, as it is not reliable enough.

Instead, write a simple cron script to do this with the [**mysqldump**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) utility:

```
#!/bin/bash
outdir="/some/large/dir"
for d IN (mysql yourdb1 yourdb2) do
 mysqldump "$d" | tar czf "${outdir}/${d}.tgz"
done
```